# How can I have Enterprise and Public version of Django application sharing some code?

Tags: python, django, git

I'm building a webapp using Django which needs to have two different versions: an Enterprise version and a standard public version. Up until now, I've been only developing the Enterprise version and am now looking for the best way to separate the two versions in the simplest way while avoiding duplication of code as much as possible. The main difference between the two versions will be that they need different URLs and different Views. I intend to differentiate based on subdomain using a multi-tenant architecture, where the www.example.com is the public version, and company1.example.com hits the enterprise version.

I've come up with a couple potential solutions, but I'm not happy with any of them.

1. Separate Git repositories and entirely separate projects, with all common code duplicated. This much duplication of code is bound to be error prone where things will get out of sync and is expected to be ridden with copy-paste mistakes. This is a last-resort solution.
2. Separate Git repositories, with common code shared via Git Submodules (a single common 'base' repository containing base models and shared views). I've read horror stories about git submodules, though, so I'm wary of this solution.
3. Single Git repository containing multiple 'project' folders (public/enterprise) each with their own base urls.py, settings.py, wsgi.py, etc...) and multiple manage.py files to choose which "Project" to run. I'm afraid that this solution would become an utter mess because it wouldn't be possible to have the public and enterprise versions use different versions of the common library if one needs an update before the other.
4. Separate Git repositories, with all shared code developed as 'Re-usable apps' and installed into the python path. This would be a somewhat clean solution, but would be difficult to work with any time changes needed to be made to the common modules.
5. Single project where all features are managed via conditional logic in the views. This would be most prone to bugs and confusion of all, and I'd prefer to avoid this solution.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of solution or could anyone help me find the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What about "a single Git repository, with all shared code developed as 'Re-usable apps'"? That is configure the options enabled with the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

First you need to decide on your release process. If you intend on releasing both versions simultaneously, using the one git repository makes sense.

An overriding concern might be if you have different distribution requirements for the code, e.g. if you want the code in the public version to be publicly available and the enterprise version to be private. Then you might have to use two git repositories.

Comment: Up to now, I've only used pip to manage dependencies like this. If I have these apps as reusable apps external to the project, how would I add them to the python path? Alternatively, how would I let the different versions depend on different versions(eg. V1 vs V2, if one isn't ready to upgrade) of the common app?

Comment: If you want to upgrade versions independently of each other, that is a sign that different git repositories will be required - it also means that you need have guaranteed stable APIs, etc, so the different versions will be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using git subtree? It's an alternative to submodules, and it makes the process a little less complicated. I think Atlassian does a great job of explaining how it's used and the pros and cons. A few examples are:

- "Contents of the module can be modified without having a separate repository copy of the dependency somewhere else."
- "The sub-project’s code is available right after the clone of the super project is done."
- "Management of a simple workflow is easy."

The Atlassian link is [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

Here's also a link to git-subtree's description [file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to identify exactly which code is shared between the two projects and make that a reusable app.

Then each installation can install that django app, and then has their own site specific code as well.